# how do i make loop for each input in python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to make a loop for my script (web scraping with selenium), so i earned every match id that i got. Here's my table

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
from dataclasses import make_dataclass
import time

pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None

key = input('Please Enter The Match Id :')
url = 'https://www.vlr.gg/{}'.format(key)
path = 'C:\chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(url)

total = (driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="wrapper"]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]').text)

Agent = make_dataclass("Agent", [("Column1",str)])
df = pd.DataFrame([Agent(total)])

df = (df['Column1'].str.split(';\s*')
                    .explode()
                    .str.split(expand=True)
                    .set_axis(['Team','pb_phase','Map'], axis=1)
                    .reset_index(drop=True))

df = df[:-1]
df['match_id'] = '{}'.format(key)

df.to_csv('{}.csv'.format(key),index=False)
driver.close()
```

how do i get this code

```
key = input('Please Enter The Match Id :')
```

to loop for certain time (so i dont use script each time and input my url) that i want and get each csv from this loop

so the result of this i get csv from every match id (when i put input into 168984 and want to loop until 168987)

```
168984.csv
168985.csv
168986.csv
168987.csv
```

Comment: Do you need to use ```input()``` or can you load the data in another way, like reading in a file?

Comment: yes it is, so it will make the match id and also for inputing match id in url for selenium to work @CaptainCaveman

Comment: After ```input('Please Enter The Match Id :')```, you could ask the user if they have a second id to enter, if they say no, you could proceed, if they say yes, prompt them again to enter an id. repeat this process until they have entered all the ids.

Comment: add a conditional if/else and if 'yes' prompt for input() again. if 'no', run your script. if the user inputs multiple ids, you would need to add them to a list, then loop through the list and pass each id to your script.